# Why are my chili flowers small?

Tags: chili

[image]

[image]
Hi, I've been growing Aji Amarillo in zone 3, indoor since 15, February.

It's my very first time growing chili.
I only took them out when day temperature was little bit above 20, but I forgot to take them back at night for several days, below 10°C.

They didn't die luckly but one's leaves are huge and dropping buds.
The other one has so many thick shoots but leaves and flowers(opened) are so small.
I pruned them earlier to have more branches but I don't know which ones to be trimmed now...
I cut off some overlapping leaves, can I still get fruit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good thorough question & good illustrations; that was too cold for them, but they appear a bit dry, especially the less foliated one, and appear could use a Sparing amount of nutrient. Could be soil drainage too, if there isnt some gravel or something below the soil. The nutrient may help lot a to reduce the dropping.

Whether 3 to 4 cm of gravel in the bottom, the soil might be bit shallow: maybe could gently raise them up & add 4 to 5 cm soil beneath whats already there. If theyre on dishes then can know when theres enough water when it starts draining into the dish, and after a few hours they may draw some back up as needed.

They look pretty healthy, so maybe wouldnt trim them any more; and leaves will grow a bit to adjust catch more sun (phototropic). They might be two slightly different varieties, could explain some of the appearance differences. Havent ever been a big fan of pruning peppers, they grow the way they grow naturally & lots of their energy goes into the outward growth, which also produces well!

Really might want to right away give them some more soil & a bit of appropriate nutrient & there ought to be good time for them to thrive & produce fruit! Maybe need a bit of pollination activity too, to help the flowers set. Adequate watering without ever really drying out and temperature consistency help too.!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I was thinking about to put them in grow room for temperature consistency. It was my very first time to grow chili so I'll try again. Thank you for your advice. I will put gravel and give nutrients. It has little bit of sea compost and potting soil that's it... I'll see next few weeks what's going to happen to the flower.

Comment: Thats a good idea, and receiving plenty of light! And be sparing with the nutrient, since a small amount makes a big difference yet doesnt overwhelm them. Youre very welcome!